# How to add metrics to the model keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, metrics

I have a model and want to add new metrics rmse to existing mae and r2.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
         input_shape=(n_past, nb_features),
         units=100,
         return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(
          units=50,
          return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae', r2_keras])
```

The function of metrics (very similar to the function of r2_keras):

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return sqrt(mean_squared_error( y_true, y_pred ))
```

So just add it in metrics array, but it gives an error:

```
metrics=['mae', r2_keras, rmse]
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you paste complete stack trace.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you do not use the Keras backend. Try something like this:

    ```from keras import backend as K```

    
    ```def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
            return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))```

    
    ```model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = root_mean_squared_error, metrics=['mae', 'acc'])```